# @OneToOne mapping delete then insert instead of updating

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I've written some spring boot entities that have one-to-one relations inside. For example:

`Student` Entity

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
private StudentClub studenttClub;
```

`StudentClub` Entity

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Student student;
```

When I try to update some student club information (i.e. club_code) by using `.save` of the `Student` repository, it deletes then inserts the updated data.

> Hibernate: delete from student_club where club_code=? and student_id=?
>
> Hibernate: insert into student_club (club_code, student_id) values (?,?)

Can we make it done by only 1 statement for example like

> Hibernate: update ...

Answer (score 0):

.saveOrUpdate() method you can use it

-Calls either save() or update() on the basis of identifier exists or not. e.g if identifier exists, update() will be called or else save() will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Move @JoinColumn on StudentClub entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class StudentEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "StudentGen", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "StudentGen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    protected Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLUB")
    public StudentClubEntity club;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_CLUB")
public class StudentClubEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "StudentClubGen", sequenceName = "STUDENT_CLUB_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "StudentClubGen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    protected Long id;


    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name = "";

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public StudentEntity student;
}
```

Try to test ...

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("test");

    StudentEntity student = new StudentEntity();
    StudentClubEntity club = new StudentClubEntity();

    student.club = club;

    System.out.println("*****************************");
    student = studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);

    student.club.name = "NEW NAME";
    student = studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);

    System.out.println("*****************************");
}
```

Result

```
*****************************
Hibernate: call next value for student_seq
Hibernate: call next value for student_club_seq
Hibernate: insert into student_club (name, student_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (club, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update student_club set name=?, student_id=? where id=?
*****************************
```